# can we access iphone calendar with ipohone sdk?

Tags: iphone

is it possible to access iphone calendar with coding like  can we access its entries or put new entries to it with sdk?If yes then which version of sdk have this feature ? good answers will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EventKit framework was added in iOS 4.0. It lets you access and modify calendar event information. You might also want to take a look at the EventKitUI framework.

Comment: +1    is it possible to access iphone calender before sdk 4??

Comment: No. So make sure your code checks the the frameworks are available if you want it to run on pre iOS 4.0 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Also mark EventKit framework as optional/weak in Xcode's "Link Binary with Libraries" section, as in [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Art/LinkingLibraries_resized.png).